# PostProcessing: disable Motion Blur on specific Layers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using this for PostProcessing: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/post-processing-stack-83912

I'm working on a Fps game and in my PostProcessingProfile I enabled "Motion Blur", but it inflicts my weapons, too.

I want that my weapons stay sharp, no matter how fast i move around or if the make a animation like reloading. Is it possible to disable Motion Blur on specific Layers? Or is there another solution?